# Show navigationController with performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to show a `tabbarController` from a `tableview`. the table view is already in navigation controller, i'm using segue to show the tab bar but for some reasons the navigation controller tab goes away when the tab bar is showing. 
Here is a code snippet where segue is performed.

```
if cell.menuLbl.text! == NSLocalizedString("Our Brands", comment: "Our Brands") {

    UserDefaults.standard.set("somevalue", forKey: "somekey")
    UserDefaults.standard.set("somevalue", forKey: "somekey")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueName_", sender: self)

   //let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle : nil)
   //revealViewController.pushFrontViewController( <#UIViewController!#>, animated: true)

}
```

I'm using Userdefaults to store some data for other purpose.

Any help is appreciated.

PS. New to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Storyboard` is not set up correctly. Embed your table view controller in a Navigation Controller, this way each view controller that you segue to from your table view controller will be embedded in the Navigation Controller as well.

See below picture for how to achieve this from `Storyboard`:

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your `Storyboard` in the question. With a properly configured `Storyboard`, this should work just fine. Also, are you sure you are not hiding the navigationController from code in the TabBarController?

Comment: other controllers .... menu->viewController->tab bar (working properly) ... but this case ... menu->tab bar( no navigation bar showing).

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in the earlier time of development pushing a `UITabbarController` was forbidden. I don't know if it is still a rule, but what you can do for sure is present the TBVC modally.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do what you are trying to do. When using `UITabBarController` with a `UINavigationController` the navigation controller should always be contained within the tab bar controller, not the other way around.

The allowed configurations are:

Split View Controller -> Tab Bar Controller -> Navigation Controller -> Content View Controllers.

What you are trying to do is fighting against the framework.

**Edited to add**

If you *really* want to do this, try adding a `UITabBar` (not `UITabBarController` to the view controller's view, but you'll have to write your own code to manage handling taps and changing the view controller.

Comment: can you please suggest some code or something for this case

Comment: can i replace segue perform with simple viewController destinationcontroller?